# Finding the next value corresponding to a criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First, here's part of my data frame

```
    Dates                            Order    Value   
0   2010-12-07T10:00:00.000000000Z     In      70      
1   2010-12-07T14:00:00.000000000Z     Out     70       
2   2010-12-08T06:00:00.000000000Z     In      31       
3   2010-12-09T02:00:00.000000000Z     In      48       
4   2010-12-09T10:00:00.000000000Z     In      29       
5   2010-12-09T10:00:00.000000000Z     In      59       
6   2010-12-09T10:00:00.000000000Z     Out     31       
7   2010-12-09T14:00:00.000000000Z     Out     29       
8   2010-12-09T14:00:00.000000000Z     In      32       
9   2010-12-10T06:00:00.000000000Z     In      1        
10  2010-12-10T10:00:00.000000000Z     Out     48
```

In this code, I'm trying to find a few things:

1. The first occurrence of a 'In' in the dataframe. For that, I'm using

   > `index_1 = df[df.Order=='In'].first_valid_index()` This will result in 0, that's correct.
2. Then, I'll find the corresponding **Value** for that index with

   > `order_1 = df.at[index_1,'Value']` This will result in 70, also correct.
3. Find the ***NEXT*** time the value 70 appears in this dataframe. This is the part I'm struggling with. The values in **Value** only repeat once, and the second time it appears will **always** be on a **Out**.

Can anyone help me finish this part of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `idxmax` with `boolean indexing`:

```
val = df.loc[df['Order'].eq('In').idxmax(), 'Value']
df[df['Value'].eq(val) & df['Order'].eq('Out')]

                            Dates Order  Value
1  2010-12-07T14:00:00.000000000Z   Out     70
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, we can use index filtering with `isin`

```
val = df[
    (df["Value"].isin(df[df["Order"].eq("In")]["Value"].head(1)))
    & (df["Order"].eq("Out"))
]

print(val)
   Dates                            Order  Value
1  2010-12-07T14:00:00.000000000Z   Out     70
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following given the fact that you succesded in extracting the first index and its value:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [70,70,10,10,50,60,70]})
index_1 = 0
order_1 = 70

indices = df.index[df['value']==order_1].tolist()
next_index = indices.index(index_1) + 1
```

Comment: I don't think the index is known beforehand, also doing `index + 1` is risky, what if the `Val` column is not sorted?

Comment: @Erfan it was stated in the question that he find the index of the first occurrence. even if the `val` is not sorted the order of the indices will be find with the df; don't you think? am I missing something?

Comment: Not 100% sure, you might be right, the explanation is open to different interpretations.